What is the distribution function of a perfect fluid in the context of GR?
In the context of GR, a perfect fluid is described (cf. e.g. chapter 8.3 of [1]) by a stress-energy tensor of the form:
\begin{equation}
T_{\mu \nu} = (\rho + P) U_\mu U_\nu + P g_{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}
Here, $U^\mu$ is a timelike unit-vector field, together with an equation of state
\begin{equation}
P = w \rho
\end{equation}
that relates the pressure $P$ to the density $\rho$. On the other hand, from the viewpoint of relativistic kinetic theory (cf. formula 2.95 of [2]), the stress energy tensor of a fluid consisting out of particles of mass $m$ is given by
\begin{equation}
T^{\mu \nu} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{d^3p}{p^0} p^\mu p^\nu f(x,p),
\end{equation}
where the integration is over the mass shell of mass $m$ and where $f(x,p)$ is the distribution function of the fluid. Now the usual distribution function in the context of relativity is a Maxwell-Jüttner distribution that is given e.g. by formula 2.120 of [2], see also [3].
I was now wondering:
What is the precise distribution function $f(p)$ for a perfect fluid with equation of state $p = w \rho$? If it is a Maxwell-Jüttner distribution, what are its parameters?
References:
[1]: Sean Carroll: "Spacetime and Geometry".
[2]: Luciano Rezzolla, Olindo Zanotti: "Relativistic hydrodynamics"
[3]: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93J%C3%BCttner_distribution

What exactly is wrong with the Maxwell-Jüttner distribution? You can convince yourself that for massless particles you obtain $\rho = P/3$ (using $P$ for pressure not to confuse it with momentum) almost trivially (try comparing $T^{00} = \rho$ and $T^{ii} = P$ using your expression for energy momentum tensor keeping in mind $\int d\Omega v^i v^j =4\pi \delta^{ij}/3$). Adding mass does not conceptually change the calculation.

Thanks for the answer. The case of massless particles is clear to me. I just did not find any source, where the parameters of the Maxwell-Jüttner distribution are explicitely related to the parameter $w$ of the equation of state $P = w \rho$. Is the mass the only parameter which is of relevance here, i.e. does $P = w \rho$ with $w \neq 1/3$  and $w = w(m)$ directly follow if I set $m>0$? Thanks also for the comment regarding $P$, I updated my question to avoid confusion.

You should find that $w=1/3$ is a perfect fluid of massless particles and $w=0$ is a perfect fluid of massive, non-relativistic particles, where basically $v=0$ so $P=0$ and $\rho$ is a sum/integral over $mc^2$ rest energy contributions. I'm not sure how think about other values of $w$ in terms of particle distributions (except for interpolating between those cases). Other popular values of $w$ are $w=-1/3$ for spatial curvature, $w=-1$ for a cosmological constant, and $w=1$ for a kinetic-energy dominated scalar field, but none of those have an easy "particle" interpretation.

Thank you very much! But you know no reference, which shows, that for those exponents there does not exist a particle interpretation, i.e. no distribution function for which above formula for $T^{\mu \nu}$ holds?
